# SQL-Error when executing update statement with regexp via xmlquery on db2-luw

Tags: regex, sql-update, xquery, db2-luw

Given a database table TABLE1 with column COLUMN1 of type VARCHAR(1020).
I need to reformat some data from variable length format into a new fixed length format (The hashes are removed, the numbers are left padded with zeros until length of 10):

e.g: from "123#456#789" into "000000012300000004560000000789".

Executing the given sql-statement leads to the following error-message, which is not that helpful and only points to a broken connection:

> Error occurred during SQL query execution
>
> Ursache:
>   SQL-Fehler [08001]: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.22.29]
>   Bei Operationen auf dem der Verbindung zugrunde liegendem Socket, im Socketeingabedatenstrom oder Socketausgabedatenstrom ist ein Kommunikationsfehler aufgetreten.
>
> Fehlerposition: Reply.fill() - insufficient data (-1).  Nachricht: Unzureichende Daten. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

I am working on a DB2-LUW <strike>11.1</strike> v10.5.0.5 database, where regular expressions are not supported except in xmlqueries.

When i am replacing the second return statement with "return xs:string($COLUMN1)" the statement executes fine. So this does not look like a syntax error.

I found some informaton stating that the order of the let statements is not fixed. So i tried removing the if/then/else-logic and this resulted always  in same results, so does not seem to be an issue either.

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1
SET COLUMN1 = xmlcast(xmlquery(
        '
        if (fn:matches( $COLUMN1,"(\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})")) 
            then
                xs:string($COLUMN1)
            else
                let $part1A := fn:replace($COLUMN1, "(\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})", "$1", "i")
                let $part1B := fn:string-join(("0000000000", $part1A), "")
                let $part1C := fn:substring($part1B, fn:string-length($part1B) - 9)

                let $part2A := fn:replace($COLUMN1, "(\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})", "$2", "i")
                let $part2B := fn:string-join(("0000000000", $part2A), "")
                let $part2C := fn:substring($part2B, fn:string-length($part2B) - 9)

                let $part3A := fn:replace($COLUMN1, "(\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})", "$3", "i")
                let $part3B := fn:string-join(("0000000000", $part3A), "")
                let $part3C := fn:substring($part3B, fn:string-length($part3B) - 9)

                let $result := fn:string-join(($part1C, $part2C, $part3C), "")

                return xs:string($result)
        '
        passing COLUMN1 AS "COLUMN1"
    ) AS VARCHAR(1020))
    WHERE COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(COLUMN1 ) > 0;
```

Expectation would be to run the sql update successfully, instead of an error which leads to a broken database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 11.1 does support regular expression functions outside of XML functions

E.g `REGEXP_LIKE`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html

So, I would use an UPDATE based on something like this

```
SELECT
   RIGHT('000000000' || REGEXP_EXTRACT(t,'(\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})',1,1,'',1),10)
|| RIGHT('000000000' || REGEXP_EXTRACT(t,'(\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})',1,1,'',2),10)
|| RIGHT('000000000' || REGEXP_EXTRACT(t,'(\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})',1,1,'',3),10)
FROM
    TABLE(VALUES('test123#456#789data')) AS T(T)
```

which returns

```
 1
 ------------------------------
 000000012300000004560000000789
```

Comment: I have to correct my question regarding the version. Stage dependant, I have different db2-versions that have to be supported. The smallest one to be supported is DB2 v10.5.0.5, so there are no builtin regexp functions.

Comment: OK. Note that Db1 10.5 hits end of base support on April 30, 2020

Comment: Also, I would suggest trying to avoid the procedural logic in your XML version. I.e. maybe try to replicate my suggestion above, but using the XML (or your own compiled regex functions https://developer.ibm.com/articles/bringing-the-power-of-regular-expression-matching-to-sql/ ) as a direct replacment for the REGEXP_EXTRACTs

Comment: And, for your "error which leads to a broken database connection", do raise that with IBM Support.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works for me.

**First step:**
The problem was \d in fn.matches() works, but does not work in fn:replace(). I had to replace \d with [0-9].

```
SELECT COLUMN1 AS SOURCE, xmlcast(xmlquery(
        '
        if (not(fn:matches( $COLUMN1,"(^\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})$"))) 
            then
                xs:string($COLUMN1)
            else
                let $part1A := fn:replace($COLUMN1, "([0-9]{0,10})#([0-9]{1,10})#([0-9]{1,10})", "$1", "i")
                let $part1B := fn:string-join(("0000000000", $part1A), "")
                let $part1C := fn:substring($part1B, fn:string-length($part1B) - 9)

                let $part2A := fn:replace($COLUMN1, "([0-9]{0,10})#([0-9]{1,10})#([0-9]{1,10})", "$2", "i")
                let $part2B := fn:string-join(("0000000000", $part2A), "")
                let $part2C := fn:substring($part2B, fn:string-length($part2B) - 9)

                let $part3A := fn:replace($COLUMN1, "([0-9]{0,10})#([0-9]{1,10})#([0-9]{1,10})", "$3", "i")
                let $part3B := fn:string-join(("0000000000", $part3A), "")
                let $part3C := fn:substring($part3B, fn:string-length($part3B) - 9)

                let $result := fn:string-join(($part1C, $part2C, $part3C), "")

                return xs:string($result)
        '
        passing COLUMN1 AS "COLUMN1"
    ) AS VARCHAR(1020)) AS REPLACEDBY
FROM
    TABLE(VALUES('123#456#789'),('test123#456#789data')) AS TABLE1(COLUMN1);
```

returns

```
SOURCE              | REPLACEDBY
---------------------------------------------
123#456#789         | 000000012300000004560000000789
test123#456#789data | test123#456#789data
```

**Second step:** Avoiding the procedural logic leads to

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN1 AS SOURCE,
    RIGHT('000000000' || xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:replace($COLUMN1, "([0-9]{0,10})#([0-9]{1,10})#([0-9]{1,10})", "$1", "i")' passing COLUMN1 AS "COLUMN1") AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)
    || RIGHT('000000000' || xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:replace($COLUMN1, "([0-9]{0,10})#([0-9]{1,10})#([0-9]{1,10})", "$2", "i")' passing COLUMN1 AS "COLUMN1") AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)
    || RIGHT('000000000' || xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:replace($COLUMN1, "([0-9]{0,10})#([0-9]{1,10})#([0-9]{1,10})", "$3", "i")' passing COLUMN1 AS "COLUMN1") AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)
    AS REPLACEDBY
FROM
    TABLE(VALUES('123#456#789'),('test123#456#789data'),('0#0#0')) AS TABLE1(COLUMN1)
WHERE 
    0 <> xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($COLUMN1,"(^\d{0,10})#(\d{1,10})#(\d{1,10})$")' passing COLUMN1 AS "COLUMN1") AS INTEGER);
```

returns

```
SOURCE              | REPLACEDBY
---------------------------------------------
123#456#789         | 000000012300000004560000000789
0#0#0               | 000000000000000000000000000000
```